# Replacement for ScalaCompile in gradle when switching to Kotlin

Tags: scala, kotlin, gradle

I convert a project that was originally written in Scala into kotlin. It is a typical backend - frontend-design with the backend written in Scala and the Frontend in Angular (the code was written by a former co-worker who is no longer working in this project)

During the gradle-build, the e2e-tests are evaluated. For this purpose the backend is compiled in the following way:

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.tasks.scala.ScalaCompile

class ScalaCompilerPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {

        project.configurations {
            scalaCompilerPlugin
        }

        project.afterEvaluate {
            project.tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
                options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
                if (scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters == null) {
                    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = []
                }
                scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters <<
                        "-Xplugin:" + project.configurations.scalaCompilerPlugin.asPath
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The 'scalaCompilerPlugin'-plugin is then added to the build.gradle-file in the backend.

```
plugins {
    id 'scala'
    id 'com.github.psxpaul.execfork' version '0.1.12'
}
apply plugin: ScalaCompilerPlugin

// ...
```

Since now the project is converted to Kotlin/Ktor I plan to use something like a KotlinCompiler-plugin for the same purpose, but in gradle 6.0.1, there seems to be no such plugin, and not being that firm with gradle I don't know how to add org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.

How can I achieve the same and start the backend during the gradle-build to run the e2e-tests during the test-runs? I am also open to suggestions to change this design.

Comment: Your `ScalaCompilerPlugin ` is actually not a compiler plugin, but a gradle plugin. It configures `ScalaCompile` task by setting actual compiler plugin for scala compiler. What do this compiler plugin does? It runs e2e-tests (that would be weird)? It adds support for some custom scala language constructs (that would be redundant if you move to Kotlin)?

Comment: There is [gradle plugin for Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html) (latest version requires Gradle 5.4+; kotlin-multiplatform requires Gradle 6.0+). Also Kotlin compiler supports compiler plugins. But are you sure you need the latter? What do you want to tweak in compilation process?

Comment: To clarify, my main problem is the line project.tasks.withType(ScalaCompile)